# Use a Windows-Runtime-Component in a Typescript-Application

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winjs

I created a WinJS-Application [Windows-10-UWP] converted the code to Typescript. 
Now I have a Windows-Runtime-Component, which I want to refer to in my .ts files. 
I allready achieved this in the normal javascript by following the instructions given [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/winjs-application-with-windows-runtime-component-to-access-n/). But I have no idea to achieve this in Typescript. The main problem here is, that I am not able to create a reference to the Window-Runtime Component. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main problem here is, that I am not able to create a reference to the Window-Runtime Component. Is this even possible?

Yes, it is possible. If you have referenced the Windows Runtime Component in your main project. The namespace will be stored in the global `window` object. So you can access the Windows Runtime Component like below:

```
let variable= window["MyTestComponent"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reoly. I will Test it as soon as possible

Comment: It works, but i get the message that there is a typedef missing and i don't know which type is needed here.

Comment: use `any` type: let variable:any=window["MyTestComponent"].